# How to filter out specific values from Objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

Lets say i have this object

```
 "errors": {
        "name": {
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "message": "Minimum length 6 characters.",
            "properties": {
                .
                .
                .
            },
            "kind": "minlength",
            "path": "name",
            "value": "Ju"
        },
        "passcodeConfirm": {
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "message": "Passwords do not match!",
             "properties": {
                .
                .
                .
            },
            "kind": "user defined",
            "path": "passcodeConfirm",
            "value": "judydoes@gmail.com"
        }
    },
```

Now, i want to only filter out the `path` and `message` from these multiple objects, This should look like this

```
{
status: "Error",
code: 404,
errors: {
  type: "validation error",
  fields: [
    {
      name: errors.path, // "Name field"
      message: errors.message, // "Error message"
    },
    {
      name: errors.path,
      message: errors.message,
    },
    //
    //
    //
  ],
},
```

}

How do i achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the values of `errors` object and pick `name` and `message` values from each object and then push them in another array as an object during the iteration.

```
    let fields=[];
    Object.values(errors).forEach(object=>{
      fields.push({
        name: object.path,
        message: object.message
      })
    })
```